# Writing a function as a power series

Tags: power-series

I've been having some issues with this function.

$$
f(x) =\dfrac{4x^2}{(x-3)^2}
$$
I've been able to take $4x^2$ out, and differentiate it to give me
$$
4x^2 \dfrac{d}{dx}(-1)(\dfrac{1}{-3-(-x)})
$$
However, I'm not sure what to do with the $-3$, as to write it as a power series, it has to be $1$. Thanks!

Comment: What about having $\frac 43 x^2$ out ? You get your $\frac 1{1-x/3}=\sum (x/3)^n$...

Comment: @zwim so then would it look like:
4/3x^2 d/dx (-1) (1/1-x) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the error, turns out I cannot take derivatives of polynomials correctly. Thank you @zwim**

Take 
$$
g(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x-3)^2}
$$

and integrate to get
$$
\int g(x)dx = \dfrac{-1}{x-3} = \dfrac{1}{3-x} = \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{x}{3}}
$$

if $u=\frac{x}{3}$ then
$$
\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{1-u} = \dfrac{1}{3}(1+u+u^2+...) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{3}+\dfrac{x^2}{9}+...\right) 
$$

Now this is the series for $\int g(x)dx$, so we need to differentiate and get

$$
\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{2x}{27}+\dfrac{3x^2}{81}+...
$$

finally we multiply by $4x^2$ to get that

$$
f(x) = \dfrac{1\cdot 4x^2}{9}+\dfrac{2\cdot 4x^3}{27}+... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(n+1)\cdot 4x^{n+2}}{3^{n+2}}
$$

Comment: wait, i don't think this works. The first term is definitely 4x^2/9, but after that, the subsequent terms don't work.

Comment: You're right after plotting this it is slightly off, I'm not sure where my error is

Comment: @wjmccann you derived $x^n$ to $x^{n-1}$ instead of $nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: @zwim so how does that change the solution? what is n in this case?

Comment: You're right @zwim. Turns out that polynomials are the hardest function to differentiate haha

Comment: @wjmccann what would the radius of convergence be then? I tried the ratio test but i think i messed up.

Comment: @johnners17 what did you get? I am fairly certain the ratio test works in this case

Comment: @wjmccann I got 3, which was right! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Define $x=3t$
$$f(x) =\dfrac{4x^2}{(x-3)^2} \implies f(t)=\frac{4 t^2}{(1-t)^2}$$ Now, use the binomial theorem for
$$(1-t)^{-2}$$ and multiply the result by $4t^2$.

When finished, replace $t$ by $\frac x3$.

Comment: i'm still confused. I did what you said, and ended up with a term with x but no n, so how would it be a power series?

Comment: @johnners17. You should end with $(4t^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+n)t^n$ which makes $\cdots\qquad $???

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wiki-Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to obtain the expansion for example:

[image]